# In my from date select box I want to show date range in between current session date range

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, date

[image]

In my current login session, I have

```
 var start_date = "<?php $this->session->userdata('start_date'); ?>";
 var end_date   = "<?php $this->session->userdata('end_date'); ?>";
```

for example :

```
$start_date = 2019-04-01 
$end_date   = 2020-03-31
```

In my from date selector box, it selects out of session date I want to select date only in between current session date.

my code:

```
<div class="row">
                 <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label >From Date</label>
                       <input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control" id="from_date_bk" 
                          name="from_date_bk" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-date-end-date="0d">
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label >To Date</label>
                     <input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control" id="to_date_bk" 
                        name="to_date_bk" data-date-end-date="0d">
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var start_date = "<?php $this->session->userdata('start_date'); ?>";
    var end_date   = "<?php $this->session->userdata('end_date'); ?>";
    var date       = new Date();
    var today      = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    $('#from_date_bk').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
              todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            onClose: function( selectedDate )
            {
                $( "#to_date_bk" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
     $('#to_date_bk').datepicker({
      uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
              todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            onClose: function( selectedDate )
        {
            $( "#from_date_bk" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $('#to_date_bk').datepicker( 'setDate', today );
  });
</script>
```

How can I select a date between the current session date.

Comment: where is the `#from_date_bk` element?

Comment: @HastaDhana I update my code, please check

Answer (score 2):

You can use `minDate` and `maxDate` like this

```
minDate: moment("01/04/2019"),
maxDate: moment("31/03/2020"),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to use the `yy/mm/dd` date format on your inputs, you could try it like this :

```php
<script>
    <?php
    $start_date = $this->session->userdata('start_date'); // example output : '2019-04-01'
    $end_date   = $this->session->userdata('end_date'); // example output : '2020-03-31'
    ?>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var start_date = "<?php echo date("Y/m/d", strtotime($start_date)); ?>";
        var end_date = "<?php echo date("Y/m/d", strtotime($end_date)); ?>";
        var date = new Date();
        var today = date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate(); // month is 0 based index, so it have to be +1 to get current month, example output : '2019-09-07'
        $('#from_date_bk').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            minDate: start_date,
            maxDate: end_date,
            onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                if (selectedDate) {
                    $("#to_date_bk").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            }
        });
        $('#to_date_bk').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            minDate: start_date,
            maxDate: end_date,
            onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                if (selectedDate) {
                    $("#from_date_bk").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                }
            }
        });
        $('#to_date_bk').datepicker('setDate', today);
    });
</script>
```

This will set :

- both input : a range from supplied `$start_date` as starting range, and `$end_date` as ending range by default.
- `#from_date_bk` input : a range from `$start_date` to `#to_date_bk` after `#to_date_bk` is filled.
- `#to_date_bk` input : a range from `#from_date_bk` to `$end_date` after `#from_date_bk` is filled.

I've added `if` conditional in `onClose` so it won't set the opposite datepicker rule if the selected date is empty.